# how to validate xpath using python xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xpath

How to validate the given xpath using python. In below code I am getting values based on the xpath given. Before that i need to validate the xpath for valid one.

```
def getElementsData(xpath):
    elements = list()
    for elem in root.findall(xpath):
        elements.append(elem.text)
    return elements
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 1):

use the excellent [`lxml` library](http://lxml.de/), it can use xpath:

```
d = lxml.etree.fromstring(your_xml) # if html use lxml.html.fromstring
try:
    result = d.xpath(some_xpath_expression)
except lxml.etree.XPathEvalError:
    print('The expression is invalid')

if not result:
    print('Expression is valid but no results')
else:
    print('Expression valid! {} results found'.format(len(result)))
```

Comment: How to validate the xpath in xml.etree.ElementTree without using the lxml lib

Comment: @Jarvis Why not use `lxml`?? It is a great library, really fast (based on the C library libxml2) and works nicely with xpath!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer we can achieve it as below

```
def validate(xpath):
    if root.findall(xpath):
        print("valid")
    else:
        print("not valid")
```